# Striped cloth detection using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to detect horizontal and vertical striped patterns in cloth pictures. Two examples of pictures that should be detected are:

[image] [image]

My first approach was trying to use a Hough Line detector. The problem is the clothes are often deformed or wrinkled so the lines aren't straight and the detector fails.

It can be assumed that the lines are horizontal or vertical with a deviation of a few degrees (horizontal and vertical striped patterns). Also that the lines are parallel

What would be a good approach to detect such slightly deformed lines?

Comment: Did you try the LSD (line segment detector) instead of Hough lines?

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try this one.

Comment: hasn't openCV a haar finder functionality? you could train it to recognize striped clothes

Comment: @GilLevi Thanks! I ended using LSD and it detect lines WAY BETTER than hough. Note that LSD is not included in OpenCV 2.x, but you can find the same implementation with header files here: https://github.com/23pointsNorth/lsd_opencv

Comment: I think it's included in OpenCV3: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Convert the image to gray scale
- Calculate the gradient (for example, using sobel)
- Take horizontal and vertical projections of the gradient image
- Threshold the projections and count the peaks

I quickly tried this in Matlab. You can try it with opencv. Use reduce function to take the projections. Below is the Matlab code and some results:

```
im = imread('pRfUL.jpg');
gr = rgb2gray(im);
h = fspecial('sobel');
grad = imfilter(gr, h) + imfilter(gr, h'); % quick gradient

hpr = sum(grad);
vpr = sum(grad');

figure,
subplot(2,2,1), imshow(gr), title('gray scale')
subplot(2,2,2), imshow(grad), title('gradient')
subplot(2,2,3), plot(hpr), title('horizontal projection')
subplot(2,2,4), plot(vpr), title('vertical projection')
```

[image]

**EDIT**

One possible improvement would be to consider horizontal and vertical cases separately. So, there would be two passes through the image for each cases (this might perform better for noisy/textured cases, and as Nallath pointed out- I think he's referring to bilateral filtering-, you can use some additional filtering). That is, when you look for horizontal strips, use the horizontal filter which will give strong responses for horizontally oriented edges. Same for vertical case.

```
grad = imfilter(gr, h); % for strong horizontal responses in the above code. use grad = imfilter(gr, h') for vertical
```

The result for horizontal case: note that the horizontal projection and the vertical offset have dropped significantly

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed answer. It sounds like a simple and great idea. The only problem i can see here is heavy textured/noisy images, but some processing on image/gradient/projections  should fix those scenarios. Im going to try this too.

Comment: You can remove noise by applying median/gausian (or any other kind of) blur. OpenCV even has a far better noise removal algorithm tucked in the image processing part. Its damn slow, but gives great results.

Comment: Thanks dhanushka, processing the horizontal and vertical cases separately is indeed a good improvement considering the given scenario and conditions.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it works very well in pure horizontal and vertical scenarios. If you are dealing with random orientations, then i have to say that the LSD (line segment detector) gave me very good results.